# The order of command execution in Unity 5 using StartCoroutine / yield return www

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are 2 c# scripts, attached to the same game object (Unity 5.4)

```
public class SignIn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SendRequest sendRequest;

    void Start()
    {
        sendRequest = GetComponent<SendRequest>();
    }

    public void signInPressed()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("key", "value");

        sendRequest.POST(mainSettings.appUrl, form);

        Debug.Log("SIGNIN");
    }
}
```

and

```
    public class SendRequest : MonoBehaviour {

    public WWW POST(string url, WWWForm form)
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
        return www;
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute these scripts first displayed line SIGNIN, and then the server response.

How to get a response from the server first, and then continue the program?
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Have a look here :**

```
StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
return www;
```

your method returns `www` object without waiting for `WaitForRequest(www)` to finish. If you are not using `www` returned from `POST()` method why do you return it.

**How to work around it:**

pass a `delegate` parameter to fire when `coroutine` is finished.

for example:

```
sendRequest.POST(mainSettings.appUrl, form, () => { Debug.Log("SIGNIN");});
```

and definition of **`POST()`**:

```
public WWW POST(string url, WWWForm form, Action callback = null)
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www, callback));
}
```

and definition of **`WaitForRequest()`**:

```
private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www, Action callback = null)
{
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
    }

    if(callback != null)
    {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful!